# Тень к JLabel

Tags: java, swing

Здравствуйте. Недавно(примерно месяц) начал пользоваться SWING и сделал небольшое приложение. В нем используется отображение текста выведенного с помощью JLabel, и использующего простую разметку HTML(<i></i> и т.п.). Текст динамический. Пользователь может установить картинку на задний фон, и текст может слиться с фоном. Поэтому решил сделать тень для текста. Пытаюсь сделать уже дней 5 - 6. Перерыл множество сайтов. Есть ли какие нибудь методы? Можете подсказать пожалуйста? Если я что те не заметил, когда искал, извиняюсь. Заранее спасибо.

P.S. Нашел такой класс(вот [здесь](https://www.mail-archive.com/java2d-interest@capra.eng.sun.com/msg04491.html)). Но при попытке использовать его процессор начинает грузиться на 100%.

```
/** Label with custom painting of alpha composite shadow. */
```

private static class CustomLabel extends JLabel{

```
public CustomLabel(){
   setForeground( TEXT_COLOR );
}

@Override
protected void paintComponent( final Graphics in_Graphics ){

  final Graphics2D graphics = ( Graphics2D ) in_Graphics;

  // Remember current graphics parameters
  final Object oldTextAntialiasingHint = graphics.getRenderingHint(
    RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING );
   final Color oldForeground = getForeground();

  // Set rendering quality
  graphics.setRenderingHint( RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING,
    RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON );

  {// Paint the shadow
    final Graphics2D shadowGraphics = ( Graphics2D ) graphics.create();

    shadowGraphics.translate( SHADOW_OFFSET_X, SHADOW_OFFSET_Y );
    shadowGraphics.setComposite( AlphaComposite.getInstance(
```

AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER,
          0.7f ) );
        setForeground( SHADOW_COLOR );

```
    super.paintComponent( shadowGraphics );

    shadowGraphics.dispose();
  }

  // Paint the text
  setForeground( oldForeground );
  super.paintComponent( graphics );

  // Restore rendering quality
  if( null != oldTextAntialiasingHint ){
    graphics.setRenderingHint( RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING,
      oldTextAntialiasingHint );
  }
  else{
    // do nothing
  }

}

private static final Color TEXT_COLOR = Color.BLACK;
private static final Color SHADOW_COLOR = Color.LIGHT_GRAY;
private static final int SHADOW_OFFSET_X = 2;
private static final int SHADOW_OFFSET_Y = 3;
```

}

P.P.S Пытался так же сам написать код, но плохо вышло) Код вот такой:

```
JLabel pElement = textPane;
    Font font = pElement.getFont();
    Integer xMargin = Math.round(Math.round(Double.parseDouble(sets.getSetting("shadowMarginWidth", "0"))));
    Integer yMargin = Math.round(Math.round(Double.parseDouble(sets.getSetting("shadowMarginHeight", "0"))));
    Integer shadowXMargin = pElement.getSize().width / 2;
    Integer shadowYMargin = pElement.getSize().height / 2;

    if (sets.getSetting("shadowMarginType", "%").equals("%")) {
        xMargin = publicFunctions.calculatePersentSize(shadowXMargin, 100 - Double.parseDouble(sets.getSetting("shadowMarginWidth", "0")));
        yMargin = publicFunctions.calculatePersentSize(shadowYMargin, 100 - Double.parseDouble(sets.getSetting("shadowMarginHeight", "0")));
    }

    shadow.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
    shadow.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.TOP);

    int fontWidth = 0;
    FontMetrics fm = pElement.getFontMetrics(new Font(font.getName(), font.getStyle(), font.getSize()));
    String[] lines = pElement.getText().replace("<br />", "\n").replaceAll("<(/?[^\\>]+)\\>", "").split("\n");
    for (String line : lines) {
        int curLineWidth = fm.stringWidth(line);
        if (curLineWidth > fontWidth) {
            fontWidth = curLineWidth;
        }
    }
    int fontHeight = (fm.getLeading() + fm.getMaxAscent() + fm.getMaxDescent()) * lines.length;

    shadowXMargin = shadowXMargin - fontWidth / 2;
    shadowYMargin = shadowYMargin - fontHeight / 2;

    switch (sets.getSetting("shadowXAligment", "right")) {
        case "left":
            shadowXMargin = shadowXMargin - xMargin;
            break;
        case "right":
            shadowXMargin = shadowXMargin + xMargin;
            break;
    }

    switch (sets.getSetting("shadowYAligment", "down")) {
        case "up":
            shadowYMargin = shadowYMargin - yMargin;
            break;
        case "down":
            shadowYMargin = shadowYMargin + yMargin;
            break;
    }

    Integer labelXSize = pElement.getSize().width - shadowXMargin;
    Integer labelYSize = pElement.getSize().height - shadowYMargin;

    backPanelLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
            backPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(pElement, pElement.getSize().width, pElement.getSize().width, pElement.getSize().width)
            .addGroup(backPanelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(shadowXMargin)
                    .addComponent(shadow, labelXSize, labelXSize, labelXSize)
            )
    );
    backPanelLayout.setVerticalGroup(
            backPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(pElement, pElement.getSize().height, pElement.getSize().height, pElement.getSize().height)
            .addGroup(backPanelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(shadowYMargin)
                    .addComponent(shadow, labelYSize, labelYSize, labelYSize)
            )
    );
```

(Пользователь сам может задать отступы в пикселях или процентах. Но когда тестировал сам, то столкнулся с тем, что тень не статично стоит, а смещается из-за типа шрифта(Жирный, курсив и т.п.)

Comment: Вопрос решен. Сделал по новой(и другой технологии) свой код. Заработало:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А если попробовать смешать Swing и JavaFX? У последней довольно просто реализуется тень к надписям и вообще каким-либо объектам интерфейса. Я вариантов с тенью в Swing не встречал, да и сам не сталкивался, а вот JavaFX может это сделать быстро.

Может быть, вот [эта](http://lj4newbies.blogspot.ru/2008/03/shadow-text-effect-on-jlabel.html) ссылка вам поможет как-то.

Comment: Я попробую дома сделать по примеру с ссылки, спасибо. А не могли бы вы подсказать, как можно смешать JavaFX и swing?

Comment: Если я правильно понял(ещё не использовал сам просто), то просто создается дополнительная панель JFXPanel, на которую располагаются объекты интерфейса, как, например, Text, и эта панель может добавляться на фремы или на другие панели.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо. Буду копать в глубь и пробовать))